# Trying to generate dialog with android

Tags: android, dialog

Anyone know why my button isn't showing up in the dialog window?

```
    Dialog d = new Dialog(AddContact.this);

    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Service.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    ViewGroup contentView = (ViewGroup) li.inflate(R.layout.dialog,null);

    d.setContentView(contentView);
    d.setTitle("Please correct these errors:");

    TextView error = (TextView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Button closer = (Button) contentView.findViewById(R.id.button1);

    closer.setText("Close");
    error.setText(errorMessage);
    d.show();
```

This my dialog.xml layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="5dp">

    <TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" />

    <Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

What do I need to do so my button shows in the dialog window?

Comment: You should tell what does the logs say when it crashes, it usually explains a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dialog is not visible when you use `findViewById()`, which means that the view with that id is not yet in your view hierachy and can not be found. This results in `error` beeing `null`, which will throw a `NullPointerException` in the following line.

You can solve this by inflating the layout seperately and use `findViewById()` on the inflated view.

```
Dialog d = new Dialog(AddContact.this);
LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Service.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
ViewGroup contentView = (ViewGroup)  li.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
d.setContentView(contentView);
d.setTitle("Please correct these errors:");
error = (TextView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
error.setText(errorMessage);
d.show();
```

Comment: Thanks, any idea why if I add a button it doesn't show up in the dialog? I've adjusted my code up top to reflect it.

Comment: If you add it in the layout XML? Should work in theory. Your `LinearLayout` is set to a horizontal orientation, maybe it's invisible because it is rendered outside of the screen *(depending on the TextView width)*. Try setting it to vertical instead. Apart from that I can not tell much without seeing the updated layout/code. Please open a new question when you can't find the problem and include the updated layout/code.

Comment: Add: Ops, should not post here at 3 am. Didn't see your updated code. Guess it's rendered like described above, the XML seems fine in general.

Comment: I've exceeded my question alottment for today. I'll try tomorrow if I don't figure it out.